# Не срабатывает data-metod="post"

Tags: yii2

в папке common/widget создан виджет header где есть вот такой код

```
<li><a href="<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/site/logout']) ?>" data-method="post" ><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i><?=Yii::t('app','LOGOUT');?></a></li>
```

пробовал и так

```
<?= Html::a('<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>'.Yii::t('app','LOGOUT'),Url::to(['/site/logout']),['data-method'=>'post']); ?>
```

вот такие ассеты во фронтенде

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        ...
            ];
    public $js = [
       ...
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

и два

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class IndexAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
      ...
    ];
    public $js = [
        ...
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

пытаюсь отработать loguot получаю такой ответ `Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST.` Поечему и что я делаю на так?

Comment: Какая версия YII2 (для 2.0.4 есть баг: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8419) и подключается ли jquery на клиентской стороне?

Comment: @DmitryNevzorov версия 2.0.7  <script src="/assets/6ee2cdb7/jquery.js"> оно ?

Comment: А существует ли путь /site/logout? ```Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/site/logout'])``` предполагает, что ссылка будет вести на /site/logout/ - тут никакой ошибки нет?
Если jquery действительно подключается, то глядя на asset'ы ничего нельзя сказать - тут код контроллера нужен, похоже. Проверьте, jquery работает? Если да - то причина не в asset'ах.